# Ember.js / Handlebars.js error parsing attribute name in handlebars template

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm just starting to have a look at Ember.js and am having problems with handlebars templates that contain templated attributes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/handlebars-1.0.0.beta.6.js" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ember-1.0.pre.js" />
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="say-hello">
    <p>First name: {{name.firstName}}</p>
    <p>Last name: {{name.lastName}}</p>
    <p>Last full: {{name.fullName}}</p>

    <a href="#" {{action "edit" on="click"}}>Edit</a>

</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Hello World!</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

I get an error in Chrome:

```
This page contains the following errors:

error on line 14 at column 10: error parsing attribute name
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
```

I also get an error in Firefox.

I guess this is the browser trying to validate the document, is there any way to avoid this and still keep the doctype?

Comment: hey, I new to ember too. I don’t think this error has anything to do with the doctype. What code do you have in the "say-hello" template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like handlebars templates are not valid xhtml.

The content type that tomcat was sending with my file was (application/xhtml+xml). This happens when you use the extension .xhtml on a document.

When this happens it makes no difference what your doctype in the document is, xhtml validation occurs in the document, and it fails to load.

In my case I guess I can precompile the handlebars templates to make it work in xhtml.

Comment: XHTML is yesterday. Probably should consider moving on without it.

Comment: Sometimes I wish I could, unfortunately I would like to embed ember in some legacy sites where I don't fancy changing the doctype or changing everything from xhtml to html.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the XHTML doctype is the issue. Have you tried using the HTML 5 doctype `<!DOCTYPE html>`?

Comment: Sorry, new to stack overflow, I ran over my character limit for a reply, see below for my resolution.